# Using discord.py is there a way to read an embed and store part of the embed as a variable?

Tags: python, discord.py

i have tried looking for keywords inside of the embed but this gives me an error saying that type is not iterable, its for a discord bot game, i want it to read the profile embed and then store the players stats as variables, but i cant find a way to do this.

```
@bot.command(name='dungeon')
async def dungeon(ctx):
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        embeds = message.embeds # return list of embeds
        for embed in embeds:
            print(embed.to_dict())
            if '**AT**' in embeds[0]:
                print('found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over items in the embed and look for the `item.name` or `item.value`.

The first line is to take only the first embed in the message you can edit that to loop them all.

P.S I added the method on how can you update the item name or value. if you want to do so.

```py
embed = message.embeds[0]
for i, item in enumerate(embed.fields):
    if "**AT**" in item.name:
        print(f'found {item.value}')
        
        # to update the embed 
        embed.set_field_at(index=i, name=item.name, inline=item.inline, value='NEWVALUE')

await message.edit(embed=embed)
```